# Is size of any data structure dividable by size of int?

Tags: c

Can I guarantee that the size of any data structure is dividable by size of `int` because of data alignment? I didn't find information about how to guess the size of the data structure before compiling.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309089/why-does-size-of-the-struct-need-to-be-a-multiple-of-the-largest-alignment-of-an

Comment: Re “information about how to guess the size of the data structure before compiling”: C implementations are required to document the sizes and alignment requirements of their types, so seek that information in the compiler documentation. Then normal C implementations lay out their structures as given by [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906915/298225). Only if there were some special purpose to be served would additional padding be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you cannot make this assumption:

- If `sizeof(int) == 1`, all structures have a size that is a multiple of `sizeof(int)`. This is the case on a few DSP chips.
- Otherwise, on the vast majority of architectures, the sizes can be arbitrary and for example the size of `struct A { char c; }` may be `1`, which is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.
- If the structure does have an `int` member that is not a bit-field, and is not explicitly or implicitly declared as *packed* with a compiler specific extension, you can assume that its size is a multiple of `_Alignof(int)` and has itself an alignment at least as large as `_Alignof(int)`. This is true for any member type (except bit-fields). Note that it does not necessarily make the size a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.
- See how struct alignment is usually determined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906915/4593267) by Eric Postpischil.
- See also [why does size of the struct need to be a multiple of the largest alignment of any struct member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309089/why-does-size-of-the-struct-need-to-be-a-multiple-of-the-largest-alignment-of-an).

Comment: @moamen: the text in the link, *data are always aligned as 4 bytes package which leads to insert empty addresses between other member’s address* is not precise enough. Padding may be inserted between some structure members or at the end of the structure to allow for proper alignment of all members, but my `struct A` has no such requirement. On most architectures its size will be `1`. Whether `sizeof(struct A)` may be larger than `1` on a conforming implementation is a separate question.